Different CLOB for ONTR securities
I was trying to find the list of all the CLOB for on-the-run UST.
I know the following: BrokerTec, TradeWeb which both have different CLOB for ONTR UST.
I think Virtu Financial also has one, but I am not quite sure.
So I was wondering if there's a list of all the CLOB available to trade ONTR UST. If there was the volume traded on each platform that would be awesome.
